# array vs binary search in different circumstances

Tags: algorithm, sorting, data-structures

I've been looking around **binary search tree vs array** and was curious if my assumptions were correct. So I will explain what I understand and you correct me if you think so. Let's also assume that we want to create a data structure that can:

**Question :**
Though, the only difference is, with array, insert is more time consuming - i.e O(n) > O(log(n)). Other than that, specific element is found in the same time and biggest/smallest even in O(1). Is sorted array's insert time the reason why we decide to use binary search tree ? does O(n) really make that difference for us so that we switch to use binary search tree with O(log(n)) ?

Comment: Insertion into a sorted array isn’t O(nlogn). It’s O(n).

Comment: You don’t need to re-sort the array if you insert the item in the correct position.

Comment: Ah, it's O(n) x O(log(n)) right ? and you treat it as O(n) ?

Comment: +, not ×: O(log n) to find the right position, and O(n) to insert the element at that position.

Comment: True, sorry. Thanks @KonradRudolph, Updated. Would you answer 2nd question ? now I am even more interested in 2nd question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Question 1: I'm wondering if my time complexities are written
> correctly. Thoughts ?

In the tree representation, nothing prevents you from storing pointers to the `min` and `max` elements, so it can be `O(1)` depending on the implementation.

> Question 2: It turns out that I like the 2nd(sorted array) and
> 3rd(binary search) options the most.

The bigger your dataset the bigger difference it makes, but `O(log(N))` is usually way closer to `1` than to `N`:

- When N is 1: `N = 1` vs `log(N) = 1`
- When N is 10: `N = 10` vs `log(N) = 4`
- When N is 1_000: `N = 1000` vs `log(N) = 10`
- When N is 1_000_000: `N = 1000000` vs `log(N) = 20`
- When N is 1_000_000_000: `N = 10000000000` vs `log(N) = 30`